# Pairwise interaction pandas columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I want to make columns with the pairwise interactions of my existing columns. The code below returns all the possible interactions (two-way, three-way and so on) while I want only the pairs of columns. Any idea on how to make it work would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

for i in range(0, df.columns.size):
    for j in range (i + 1, df.columns.size):
        col1 = str(df.columns[i])
        col2 = str(df.columns[j])
        nam = col1 + "X" + col2
        df[nam] = pd.Series(df[col1] * df[col2], name=nam)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of tricky but the following is happening, df.columns.size is changing in the loop since you are creating new columns, you can just create size_col outside the loop so it won't be computed every time:

```
import pandas as pd

size_col = df.columns.size
for i in range(0, size_col):
    for j in range (i + 1, size_col):
        col1 = str(df.columns[i])
        col2 = str(df.columns[j])
        nam = col1 + "X" + col2
        df[nam] = pd.Series(df[col1] * df[col2], name=nam)
```

Comment: @Uni13 Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import itertools
for x in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    df[x[0]+"X"+x[1]] = df[x[0]]*df[x[1]]
```

Edit: Solution without itertools

```py
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)


k = 3
for x in combinations(df.columns, k):
    df["X".join(x)] = df[list(x)].prod(axis=1)
```

I also updated the code so that you can specify k to be whatever you want. Combination function from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the df is changing size as you iterate through the inner loop and change the df columns.

To fix this, define another variable before the loop that won't change in size.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[3,4,5]})

orig_size = df.columns.size

for i in range(0, orig_size):
    nam = []
    for j in range (i + 1, orig_size):
        col1 = str(df.columns[i])
        col2 = str(df.columns[j])
        nam = col1 + "X" + col2 
        df[nam] = pd.Series(df[col1] * df[col2], name=nam)
```

---

Output in terminal:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  aXb  aXc  bXc
0  1  2  3    2    3    6
1  2  3  4    6    8   12
2  3  4  5   12   15   20
```